# Constructive Resolution of Toric Singularities via Model Theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, model-theory, toric-varieties, resolution-of-singularities

Do there exists some language $\mathcal{L}$ of rational polyhedral cones in rational vector spaces and a theory $T$ over $\mathcal{L}$ whose models $\mathcal{M}$ are resolutions of toric singularities?

The motivation of this question is that if such theory exists, a constructive 
resolution of toric singularities may be a quantifier-free theory equivalent to $T$.